# Get posts by category via ajax

Tags: ajax

In my `page-members.php` I output my list of categories

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'slug'
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '"><div class="category-block">' . $category->name . '</div></a>';
    }
?>
```

I'd like for a click on those links to fill the right column with the posts of that category.

I have a js file loaded for this page; my `functions.php`:

```
if (is_page()) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_name == 'members') {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array(), '', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/blog.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
        wp_localize_script('blog', 'ajaxposts', array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        ));
    }
}
```

My `blog.js` loads appropriately only on the members page.

### What can I put into `blog.js` to load posts by category?

Comment: Is the second block of code inside a hook callback function? You must use `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook to enqueue scripts and styles.

Answer (score 0):

Add the category ID to category list items `<div class="category-block" data-cid="{ID-OF-CAT}">`, you will need it in the ajax request. You must also include `action` in the request and display received data.

[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) you can read more about AJAX in WP.

*blog.js*

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var cat_buttons = $(".category-block");
        cat_buttons.on( 'click', function(event){
            // 
            event.preventDefault();
            var cid = $(this).data('cid');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ajaxposts.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'my_action_name',
                    cat_id: cid // <-- category ID of clicked item / link
                }
            })
            .done( function(data){
                // display posts
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

You need also PHP function to handle the AJAX request:

*functions.php*

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action_name', 'ajx_handle_my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action_name', 'ajx_handle_my_action' );

function ajx_handle_my_action() {
    $category_id = (int)$_POST['cat_id'];
    //
    // read category posts

    echo json_encode( $result );    
    wp_die();
}
```